# Unity script blocks normal movement

Tags: unity, c#

I've made a script to avoid the double jump problem but, when it's active, I can't move my character without being in the air. If I comment out the double jump script, it works like a charm. This is a strange, buggy charm, because I still need to improve it.

My script looks like this:

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float Speed = 10f;
    public float Jump = 1f;

    void Start () 
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began && transform.position.y == 0.55f)
        {
            // Double Jump
            rb.AddForce(0f, 1f * Jump, 0);

            // Regular Movement
            rb.AddForce(Input.acceleration.y * Speed, .0f,  -Input.acceleration.x * Speed);
        }
    }
}
```

This is used on a sphere object, if it matters. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the poor code formatting , if anyone could also tell me how to format it properly , it would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ,I worked around it and switched the `Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began` with `Input.touchCount > 0`. Now it all works.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have `transform.position.y == 0.55f` - I hope it's supposed to be like that, assuming that your player or whoever with this script is supposed to jump only when position on y axis is 0.55.

And as I have seen in previous comments, you said that your ball on the ground is on the position 0.55, then there is no double jump at all, you just check for simple jump when your ball is on 0.55f y level.

If your script works fine without this "if" part - then it makes no sense, because part after the if should invoke anyway. You can check that by `Debug.Log("Invoked");` inside your `FixedUpdate();`.

Also it's bad practice to use this kind of logic for jump like `==`. Try checking for ground collisions, there are plenty tutorials about jumping in Unity. And why - because platforms could be on different y level - it's first. Secondly, because in Unity in world space `position.y` is a `float`value as I remember, so it's not always rounded, it can be on 0.55134f  level and you could not even notice it. Why? - Because of the collisions and update. Collisions are checked every frame and your machine(PC, Mac...) sometimes has more frames per second and sometimes less. Also it doesn't work at the same speed all the time - which means even if the collider edge is on 0.55f on y, your ball could have stopped at 0.54923f and other values like that. So it may never even be on 0.55f.

Couldn't help you more with it with the information you have provided, try first go through some tutorials and just make the same actions step by step, then try to understand how Unity works and what algorithms it uses for it. That is a long road, good luck.

Comment: So , I switched to your method ( indeed , it is better , thanks for the advice) but I have the same problem. Anyway , it gives me an error : " ArgumentException : Index Out Of Bounds" (This also was before changing my code (sorry)).

Comment: @MihaiBarbu Take a look at what other scripts you have attached to your game object. Could be something interfering.

Comment: @Byte56 On the Player object (The Sphere) I have :
- Sphere (Mesh Filter)
- Sphere Collider 
- Mesh Renderer 
- The "Player Movement" Script (The one listed above)
- Rigidbody
On the ground :
- Cube (Mesh Filter)
-Box Collider 
-Mesh Renderer
Also , both of them have a material applied.

Comment: Also , I've changed my code to the one suggested by @CandidMoon , should I also change it here ?